# write function only returns the string length without actually writing the string to the destination file

Tags: python

When I try to use the python write function to write a string into a text file the write function just returns the length of the string without actually writing the string to the destination file. Has anyone encountered the same kind of issue?

```py
f.write('let us delete the file')
```

This Returns:

```
22
```

Comment: Can you post full example, including how do you open the file?

Comment: Please post the code. It sounds like you're missing a `flush` or `close` somewhere

Answer (score 1):

f.write(string) writes the contents of string to the file, returning the number of characters written. This means it your program may work correctly. Check your text file to see if 'let us delete the file' was written to the file.

```
f.write('This is a test\n')
```

Returns:

15

[read: python inputs and outputs](http://python%20inputs%20&%20outputs)

Answer (score 0):

A simple (and working) example of writing data into a file

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    number_of_chars_written = f.write("test")
    print(number_of_chars) # only included to show return value
# Output 4
# Results in a text file test.txt with content test
```

Comment: why print() though?

Comment: The print statement is not needed. I've added it, to show the return value of write. I have changed the answer to put more emphasis on this.